# What are methods for automatic labeling of data downloaded from Google Sheets / Google Surveys?

Tags: r, database, google-sheets, google-forms, googlesheets4

Retrieving data collected using Google spreadsheets is quite convenient, but if I want to use the R package for example to create a database from this, there is a problem with nominal categories (not-numbers data). I usually use:

```
library(googlesheets4)
read_sheet(myURL)
data <- read_sheet(myURL)
write.csv(data, 'e:/my_data.csv')
```

BUT there is a problem with order of categories, after importing 'em into the database. If there is an questions in the survey with so-called likert scales answers (which take into account the *level* of some characteristics), then I'm interested in the numerical values assigned to the category in the database for the text category, in the order of the idea of scale i.e.

- 1 = no
- 2 = probably not
- 3 = i do not know
- 4 = rather yes
- 5 = yes

and who worked a bit on databases knows that the automatic import and inclusion of numbering will depend, e.g. on the order in which the answers appeared in the database - not in what order they are in the survey.

So the question arises - **is there either a library responsible for automatically encoding data according to the survey, or maybe some API for Google Forms (Questionnaires) from which I could draw the order of data and adjust it**? Maybe some other tool I had not thought about? Of course, I assume that I have access to both the questionnaire / form and the database compatible with it on my Google Account.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question, but the gargle package helps with encoding https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gargle/gargle.pdf

Comment: Thank You, @SusanSwitzer, I realized that I used the wrong word - I meant labeling, not encoding. :) Edited. :)